# Django Model: Display only corresponding values from Model DB by user selection

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create an Application in Django that displays oil parameter from a model to calculate with.

My Model.py look like:

```
#models.py
class OilModels(models.Model):
oil_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default = '')
oil_density = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 9, decimal_places = 2, default = '')
oil_temperature_1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 9, decimal_places = 2, default = '')
...
```

The oils are added in the admin.py view:

```
#admin.py
admin.site.register(OilModels)
```

I want to display the oil_name in a html select option like:

```
#index.html
<select>
{% for oil in objectlist %}
<option value="{{ oil.pk }}">{{ oil.oil_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

And then if the user selects an oil from the html select, I want to display only the corresponding values from the model like:

```
#index.html
<input type="number" value="{{oil_density}}" readonly />
<input type="number" value="{{oil_temperature_1}}" readonly />
...
```

Sadly I don't get it to work. I hope one of you has an idea and can help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to take a look at AJAX with [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for example if you don't want to refresh your whole page when the user select an oil. Or a simpler way is to use a [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) and when it is submitted you can change your page from the response with a specific oil.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with AJAX. I got a solution, that dynamically update the Dropdown and displays the Data from the Database in the console in a json format. Sadly I am not really skilled, so I don't get the JSON string to the template. The string looks like `[{"model": "Application.oilmodels", "pk": 4, "fields": {"oil_user": 1, "oil_date": "2018-02-07T14:38:15.195Z", "oil_name": "Test\u00f6l 1", "oil_density": "1.00", "oil_temperature_1": "79987.00", "oil_viscosity_1": "97.00", "oil_temperature_2": "987.00", "oil_viscosity_2": "7897.00", "oil_thermal_conductivity": "89.00"}}]`.